# Use select to do math(Sqlite)

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I'm trying to do a simple math in sqlite3.
Here's my code:

```
sqlite> select (select count(noise_value) from noise where noise_value<20)/total(select count(noise_value) from noise);
Error: near "select": syntax error
```

I got an error! But the code below works:

```
sqlite> select (select count(noise_value) from noise where noise_value<20)/total(1);
5.0
```

I just want to compute the result of A/B. 
How can I fix the first code snippet? Help!

Comment: Can you post some sample  data please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to divide number of `noise_value < 20` with all `noise_value` number.

You can use `COUNT` and `CASE WHEN` for this:

```
SELECT 1.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN noise_value < 20 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS result
FROM noise;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/169c6/2/0)**</kbd>

You can add condition to avoid divide by 0:

```
 SELECT 1.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN noise_value < 20 THEN 1 END) /
        (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(*) END) AS result
 FROM noise;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, a subquery must be written in its own pair of parentheses.
The parentheses around your second subquery actually belong to the `total()` function call. You need another pair:

```
... total((select ...)) ...
```